# Determine the minimal elements of a Dynkin system generated by a finite set of finite sets

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, computational-complexity

(This is a refined version of https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/144371)

Let $\Omega$ be a finite set.  A [Dynkin system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin_system) on $\Omega$ is a subset of the power set of $\Omega$ containing $\Omega$, which is closed under complements in $\Omega$ and which is closed under union of disjoint sets.

Given any subset $\mathcal E$ of the power set of $\Omega$, there is a unique minimal Dynkin system $\delta(\mathcal E)$, the Dynkin system generated by $\mathcal E$.

I am interested in a good algorithm that determines the elements of $\delta(\mathcal E)\setminus\{\emptyset\}$ which are minimal with respect to inclusion.

For example, given
$$
\mathcal E = \{\{1,2,3,4\}, \{1,2,3\}, \{2,3,4\}\}
$$
the minimal elements of the generated Dynkin system are
$$
\{\{1\}, \{2,3\}, \{4\}\}.
$$

Currently, I do not even have a good algorithm to check whether a subset of $\Omega$ is the set of minimal elements of $\delta(\mathcal E)\setminus\{\emptyset\}$.

Comment: I think your example is a bit misleading, because the minimal elements are disjoint. In the case of the Dynkin system $\{\{1,2\},\{2,3\},\{3,4\},\{4,1\},\{1,2,3,4\}\}$, do you consider your minimal elements to be these four pairs?

Comment: Yes, the minimal elements (atoms, actually) would be the pairs $\{\{1,2\},\{2,3\},\{3,4\},\{4,1\}\}$.  Indeed, any set partition $\mathcal E$ of $\Omega$ generates a Dynkin system such that the minimal elements of $\delta(\mathcal E)\setminus\{\emptyset\}$ are the blocks of $\mathcal E$, but these are the less interesting Dynkin systems.